# use place holder in user control to reserve a place for gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, controltemplate, webusercontrol

I have a user control that I want reserve a place inside it for filling by a GridView by each target pages.

I am using place holder and ITemplate to provide this option for my user control.

Q1: How can I force my place holder to accept just GridView tag inside it?

Q2: Or in ideal mode, is there a way that I can use place holder inside the grid? It means I write ASP:GridView tag in user control and write columns of it in target each pages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at this link, you can get the second question's answer:

[How do I expose the columns collection of GridView control that is inside a user control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915628/how-do-i-expose-the-columns-collection-of-gridview-control-that-is-inside-a-user)