# Type UserControl does not have a public property named Columns

Tags: asp.net, gridview, user-controls

I'm trying to develop a `UserControl` containing a `GridView` inside a `Panel`

```
<asp:Panel runat="server" ID="panel"> 
    <asp:GridView ID="gridView" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false">
    </asp:GridView>
</asp:Panel>
```

Code behind

```
public partial class DropDownMultiColumn : UserControl
{
    [System.Web.UI.IDReferenceProperty(typeof(DataControlFieldCollection))]
    [PersistenceMode(PersistenceMode.InnerProperty)]

    public virtual DataControlFieldCollection Columns
    {
        get { return gridView.Columns; }
        set
        {
            gridView.Columns.Clear();
            foreach (DataControlField c in value)
            {
                gridView.Columns.Add(c);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've included the control into a ASPX page, using the `Columns` public property

```
<dd:DropDownMultiColumn id="_dd_InsertStore" runat="server" DataSourceID="_dsTest" >
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MGCOD" HeaderText="MGCOD"></asp:BoundField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="MGDSC" HeaderText="MGDSC"></asp:BoundField>
    </Columns>
</dd:DropDownMultiColumn>
```

But I get the following error in Design section:
`Type 'System.Web.UI.UserControl' does not have a public property named 'Columns'`

I've tried to implement [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/915628/how-do-i-expose-the-columns-collection-of-gridview-control-that-is-inside-a-user), but it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here follows a working workaround for the issue.

**Declare a property with JSON content**

Declare `Columns` as an attribute, containing required data in JSON format

```
<dd:DropDownMultiColumn id="_ddInsertStore" runat="server" DataSourceID="_dsTest" Columns="
    [{ 'DataField':'MGCOD', 'HeaderText':'MGCOD' },
    { 'DataField':'MGDSC', 'HeaderText':'MGDSC' }]">
</dd:DropDownMultiColumn>
```

**Convert JSON to BoundField**

Within `OnLoad` event, deserialize JSON and build `BoundField` data

```
protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
{
    List<Column> columns = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Column>>(Columns);

    gridView.Columns.Clear();
    foreach (Column column in columns)
    {
        BoundField boundField = new BoundField();
        boundField.DataField = column.DataField;
        boundField.HeaderText = (string) column.HeaderText;
        gridView.Columns.Add(boundField);
    }
}
```

Declare a `Column` class, having the required properties.

```
public class Column
{
    public string DataField { get; set; }
    public string HeaderText { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Seriously?  This isn't a good "solution".